# Opening Android FileChooser with Camera option

Tags: webview, xamarin.android

Currently I have a FileChooser intent running in my WebView app. However I want to add Camera option to the File Chooser dialog. Below is the code I have so far.

The File Chooser dialog opens but there still is no Camera option.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
i.SetType("*/*");

// The camera intent
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

List<IParcelable> targetedShareIntents = new List<IParcelable>();
targetedShareIntents.Add(captureIntent);
captureIntent.AddCategory(Intent.ActionCameraButton);

//add camera intent to the main intent (i)
i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, targetedShareIntents.ToArray());

(Forms.Context as MainActivity).StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
```

What am I missing?

Screenshot of the file chooser dialog:

EDIT: image attachments are not working somehow. So here is the link to the screenshot: http://puu.sh/Bx0iY.png

Comment: Umm I see you have added a category to the intent why don't you try removing it and checking what happens

Comment: Nothing happens. Only local content without the Camera option is there in the file chooser window.